# Configuring Azure Pipeline to pull from Github hosted repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently using an Azure DevOps pipeline to trigger a `terraform plan` against an existing infrastructure.

Within this pipeline during the `terraform init` stage, terraform will analyze the scripts and download modules from an external repository. During the initial stage of running this pipeline we encountered the following error.

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

which we temporarily resolved using PAT

```
git config --global url."https://$(GITHUB-USER-ACCT):$(GITHUB-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN)@github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
```

However as this adds the additional load of maintaining a PAT, I was wondering whether we can move from this method to an method of using the GitHub Service connection (Which is automatically created when creating the pipeline) to be used as an authentication mechanism. This Service connection was created using the OAuth application. The Service connection that we used has read permissions on the centralized repository which contains the Terraform modules.

The following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) describes how to do this for a Azure Hosted repository. Is there any way to accomplish this for a Repo hosted in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that adding the PAT token is resolving temporarily already but getting the additional load, you could try below solutions once:

**Solution 1:**

1. If you're using Windows OS, open Credential Manager > Windows Credentials > Generic Credentials > Remove the credentials like git: https://github.com
   [image]

Then clone again, git will let you input the credential for the repo. After inputing the username(email address) and password which can access the VSTS account, the repo should be cloned successful.

2. Installed GIT Credential Manager for Windows. https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases
3. Open command prompt and enter command  **git fetch** and continue the work like Push, Pull etc and check once it is working good.

**Solution 2:**

Remove `C:\Users(profile)\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache` file

**Solution 3:**

Another solution is to "*Allow scripts to access the OAuth token*" in the job options:
[image]

In the git push use the System.AccessToken:
***git push*** `https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/......`

And give push permissions to the build user (in the repo settings):
[image]

Also, check this similar [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567940/azure-pipelines-i-am-getting-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github)